# How can i disable/ignore cerr output stream in JetBrains CLion?

Tags: c++, outputstream, clion, jetbrains-ide

I have a tool, that makes many cerr outputs.
if i run it over "run configuration"s in Clion i see all the cerr messages in the output window.
How can i disable some output stream in Clion/Intellij?
I use windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect the cerr output to a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream output("output.txt");
    std::streambuf* p_cerrbuffer=std::cerr.rdbuf();
    std::cerr.rdbuf(output.rdbuf()); // redirecting to a file

    std::cout<<"cout"<<std::endl; // "cout" appears on the standard output.
    std::cerr<<"cerr"<<std::endl; // "cerr" appears in the output.txt file
}
```

Comment: I was superficial. I am sorry! Unfortunatelly I don't know JetBrains CLion. If you run the application on Windows from the command promt, then the following statement may help you: "applivcation.exe 2>file.txt". Press Enter and the cerr output will redirected to the file.txt. This statement also creates the file.txt, you don't have to do it yourself.